# Removing APK from Google Play releases package name?

Tags: android, google-play

My question is simple, if I remove an application (trough deleting all it's APK files) the package name is released to be used by another developer?

Actually I hope it will, cause we uploaded a package to test in-app purchase and now it's time to upload the final version in another account.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it.  I've heard reports of people getting complete apps transferred between accounts on request though (typically between contractor and client).  But you may also be stuck with the same certificate?

Comment: The self-generated one you signed it with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there's possible to upload a package with the same name in another account if the previous was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can not delete packages that have been live once. You can only unpublish them. Also, if an app with a given package name has been uploaded, it is reserved. Neither the same account or another account can upload an app with the same package name. Period.

Comment: Actually, there's possible to upload a package with the same name in another account if the previous was deleted.

Comment: Apps can't be deleted. Thus, the package name gets tied to your account. If you try to upload an apk file on a different account under the same package you will get an error.